# NameError - uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4 and my project is about an HR App. An employee can create a leave request through his profile page BUT instead I create the form in his profile page, I only wanted to create a link_to the requests controller BUT I've got this error:

```
NameError in Employees#show Showing /home/user/workspace/hrapp/app/views/employees/show.html.erb where line #50 raised:

uninitialized constant Requests’

Extracted source (around line #50):

48 </p>
49 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_employee_path(@employee) %> 
50 <%= link_to ‘My Annual Leave Requests’, controller:'requests' %>
51 <%= link_to 'Back', employees_path %>
```

AND I tried this solution: https://hackhands.com/rails-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-class-solution/

BUT it didn't work and I didn't find a generic answer for this error.

Here is the rake routes:

```
user@snf-34155:~/workspace/hrapp$ rake routes
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                         Controller#Action
employee_requests GET    /employees/:employee_id/requests(.:format)          requests#index
                  POST   /employees/:employee_id/requests(.:format)          requests#create
                  PUT    /employees/:employee_id/requests/:id(.:format)      requests#update
                  DELETE /employees/:employee_id/requests/:id(.:format)      requests#destroy
        employees GET    /employees(.:format)                                employees#index
                  POST   /employees(.:format)                                employees#create
     new_employee GET    /employees/new(.:format)                            employees#new
    edit_employee GET    /employees/:id/edit(.:format)                       employees#edit
         employee GET    /employees/:id(.:format)                            employees#show
                  PATCH  /employees/:id(.:format)                            employees#update
                  PUT    /employees/:id(.:format)                            employees#update
                  DELETE /employees/:id(.:format)                            employees#destroy
             root GET    /                                                   welcome#index
```

I think I just need to write the right route but I tried few of them and it didn't work anyway.

Please, can anybody help?

Thanks in advance :)

**app/controllers/requests_controller.rb**

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
def index
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
  @request = @employee.requests.all
end

def show
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
  @request = @employee.requests.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
  @request = @employee.requests.new
end

 def create
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
    @request = @employee.requests.create(request_params)
    redirect_to show_employee_path(@employee)
  end

  def destroy
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
    @request = @employee.requests.find(params[:id])
    @request.destroy
    redirect_to show_employee_path(@employee)
  end

  private
    def request_params
      params.require(:request).permit(:start_date, :end_date, :considerations)
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you have controller called `requests_controller` ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem but the line with the error has a mix of single quotes and "webby" single quotes:  `<%= link_to ‘My Annual Leave Requests’, controller:'requests' %>`.  Try changing the quote style around "My annual leave requests" to be the same as that around "requests".

Comment: Yes @Pavan I just update here Î

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted

```
</p>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_employee_path(@employee) %> 
<%= link_to ‘My Annual Leave Requests’, controller:'requests' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', employees_path %>
```

It seems that the `‘My Annual Leave Requests’` is using special quote characters. Did you by any chance copy and paste that from another source?

A fix I can see is manually changing the quotes to using double quotes `"`

I noticed your error uninitialized constant Requests’ also contains a quote at the end. Have you try fixing the controller:"requests" as well?

Comment: I copied from my blog application and just changed the name and the controller, this application is based in my blog application, I'm using as example.

Comment: Do you have a controller called `RequestsController`? Whoops never mind, I see that you do

Comment: I noticed your error `uninitialized constant Requests’` also contains a quote at the end. Have you try fixing the `controller:"requests"` as well?

Comment: Now I've got this with double quotes:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Employees#show
Showing /home/user/workspace/hrapp/app/views/employees/show.html.erb where line #50 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"requests", :id=>"3"}

Comment: That's good, that's a different error which is usually good. All that new error means is that there's no route in that matchers `requests#index` with just an `id` as an argument. It seems your link is missing an `employee_id` argument. Try doing something like `<%= link_to "My Annual Leave Requests", controller:"requests", employee_id: @employee.id %>`